# Apigility Resource class methods

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas-api-tools

I am using the **Apigility** to create **Rest Web Services** except that I have a doubt. Can I add methods in the class **Resource**? If so, how can I make a call to the method with php?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add methods to you `Resource`, but they wont be called via API, in any way.

If you want to call them with PHP, then load resource by factory and call function.